# How to open new Activity from list in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I'm new to android. I've created sliding menu in my app and able to access fragments when I click on list items in drawer. Like following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    displayView(0);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new DailyPromotion();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new WeeklyPromotion();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        case 3:


            fragment = new OurProducts();
            title = getString(R.string.title_products);
            break;

        case 4:
            fragment= new AboutUsFragment();
            title= getString(R.string.title_aboutus);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

It works like a charm. But I want to open an activity when I click any item,lets say "case 0:" opens an activity instead of fragment. Thanks in advance

Comment: just write what u write for starting an activity..  :p

Comment: Thanks @thestalker. it was so simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) { displayView(position);

}



private void displayView(int position) {


    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, YourDestinationActivity.class));// add the activity
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new DailyPromotion();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new WeeklyPromotion();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        case 3:


            fragment = new OurProducts();
            title = getString(R.string.title_products);
            break;

        case 4:
            fragment= new AboutUsFragment();
            title= getString(R.string.title_aboutus);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null&&position!=0) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: @شبيرالبلوشي, Glad to help you.